# ASP classic skips javascript code and to a redirect command

Tags: asp-classic

Here's my code:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Thanks you!');</script>")
Response.Redirect "page.htm"
```

If I use this in my .asp file, I don't get the alert in the first line.
Instead I get redirected to page.htm

However, if I remove the second line - I do get the alert.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because the `Response.Redirect` is happening on the *server* before the *client-side* JavaScript renders.

Instead of

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Thanks you!');</script>") 
Response.Redirect "page.htm"
```

Why not just handle it all in JavaScript?

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Thanks you!'); window.location.href='./page.htm';</script>")
```